# Finding mapped memory from inside a process

Tags: c, linux, memory, x86-64, aslr

Setup:

- Ubuntu 18x64
- x86_64 application
- Arbitrary code execution from inside
  the application

I'm trying to write code which should be able to find structures in memory even with ASLR enabled. Sadly, I couldn't find any static references to those regions, so I'm guessing I have to use the bruteforce way and scan the process memory. What I tried to do was to scan the whole address space of the application, but that doesn't work as some memory areas are not allocated and therefore yield `SIGSEGV` when accessed. Now I'm thinking it would be a good idea to `getpid()`, then use the pid to access `/proc/$PID/maps` and try to parse the data from there.

But I wonder, is there a better way to identify allocated regions? Maybe even a way that doesn't require me to access libc (=`getpid, open, close`) or fiddle around with strings?

Comment: The `/proc/self` symlink at least lets you avoid calling getpid and formatting it as a string

Comment: .. which means opening and parsing `/proc/self/maps` is the proper interface for obtaining information on the memory regions used by the current process. You can use raw syscalls to do so, too, if you want to skip the C library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's any standard POSIX API for this.

Parsing `/proc/self/maps` is your best bet.  (There may be a library to help with this, but IDK).

You tagged this ASLR, though.  If you just want to know where the text / data / bss segments are, you can put labels at the start/end of them so those addresses are available in C.  e.g. `extern const char bss_end[];` would be a good way to reference a label you put at the end of the BSS using a linker script and maybe some hand-written asm.  The compiler-generated asm will use a RIP-relative LEA instruction to get the address in a register relative to the current instruction address (which the CPU knows because it's executing the code mapped there).

Or maybe just a linker script and declaring dummy C variables in custom sections.

I'm not sure if you can do that for the stack mapping.  With a large environment and/or argv, the initial stack on entry to `main()` or even `_start` might not be in the same page as the highest address in the stack mapping.

---

**To scan, you either need to catch `SIGSEGV` or scan with system calls instead of user-space loads or stores.**

`mmap` and `mprotect` can't query the old setting, so they're not very useful for non-destructive stuff.  `mmap` with a hint but without `MAP_FIXED` could map a page, and then you could `munmap` it.  If the actual chosen address != hint, then you could assume the address was in use.

Maybe a better option would be to scan with `madvise(MADV_NORMAL)` and check for `EFAULT`, but only one page at a time.

You could even do this portably with [`errno=0; posix_madvise(page, 4096, POSIX_MADV_NORMAL)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_madvise.3.html).  Then check `errno`: `ENOMEM`: Addresses in the specified range are partially or completely outside the caller's address space.

On Linux with [`madvise(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) you could use `MADV_DOFORK` or something that's even less likely to be at a non-default setting for each page.

**But on Linux, an even better choice for read-only querying the process memory mapping is [`mincore(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html)**:  It also uses the error code `ENOMEM` for an invalid addresses in the queried range.  "*`addr` to `addr + length` contained unmapped memory*".  (`EFAULT` is for the result vector pointing to unmapped memory, not addr).

Only the `errno` result is useful; the `vec` result shows you whether pages are hot in RAM or not.  (I'm not sure if it shows you which pages are wired into the HW page tables, or if it would count a page that's resident in memory in the pagecache for a memory mapped file but not wired, so an access would trigger a soft page fault).

**You can binary-search for the end of a large mapping by calling `mincore` with larger lengths.**

But unfortunately I don't see any equivalent for finding the next mapping after an unmapped page, which would be much more useful because most of the address-space will be unmapped.  Especially in x86-64 with 64-bit addresses!

For sparse files there's `lseek(SEEK_DATA)`.  I wonder if that works on Linux's `/proc/self/mem`? probably not.

**So maybe large (like 256MB) `(tmp=mmap(page, blah blah)) == page` calls would be a good way to scan through unmapped regions looking for mapped pages.**  Either way you simply `munmap(tmp)`, whether `mmap` used your hint address or not.

Parsing `/proc/self/maps` is almost certainly more efficient.

**But the *most* efficient thing would be putting labels where you want them for static addresses,** and tracking dynamic allocations so you already know where your memory is.  This works if you have no memory leaks.  (glibc `malloc` might have an API to walk the mappings, but I'm not sure.)

---

**Note that *any* system call will produce an `errno=EFAULT` if you pass it an unmapped address for a parameter that's supposed to point to something.**  (Unless it's actually implemented in user-space, e.g. via [Linux's VDSO](https://packagecloud.io/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/), like `gettimeofday(2)`.  Then an attempt to write via those pointer args will just segfault.  I think POSIX only specifies that *if* a function is going to return an error instead of actually segfaulting, the error code must be EFAULT.)

One possible candidate is [`access(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html), which takes a filename and returns an integer.  It has zero effect on the state of anything else, success or fail, but the downside is filesystem access if the pointed-to memory is a valid path string.  And it's looking for an implicit-length C string so could also be slow if passed a pointer to memory with no `0` byte anywhere soon.  I guess `ENAMETOOLONG` would kick in, but it still definitely reads every accessible page you use it on, faulting it in even if it was paged out.

If you open a file descriptor on `/dev/null`, you could make `write()` system calls with that.  **Or even with [`writev(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readv.2.html) : `writev(devnull_fd, io_vec, count)` to pass the kernel a vector of pointers in one system call**, and get an EFAULT if any of them are bad.  (With lengths of 1 byte each).  **But (unless the `/dev/null` driver skips reads early enough) this does actually read from pages that are valid, faulting them in unlike `mincore()`**.  Depending how it's implemented internally, the `/dev/null` driver might see the request early enough for its "return true"-without-doing-anything implementation to avoid actually touching pages after checking for EFAULT.  Would be interesting to check.