# Memory available to assembly program in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls

For fun I am just trying to write a program in assembly for Linux on a laptop with an x86 processor to get some system information. So one of the things I am trying to find is how much memory is available to my program, and where e.g. the stack is and if and how I can allocate additional memory if needed.

Long time ago I did things like this on an Atari ST and there was just a system 'malloc' I could ask memory from and there were functions to find the available memory.

I know Linux is set up differently and I kind of have the whole address space to myself, but I guess there are some memory areas I am not allowed to touch.

And somehow a default stack seems to have been setup.

I researched quite a bit for this, but I can't find any 'assembly' system call. Most people point to linking the C malloc for memory management, but I am not looking for a memory manager. I just want to know the memory boundaries of my program.

I find things like getrlimit, setrlimit, prlimit and brk and sbrk, but those seem to be C functions and not system calls.

What am i missing?

Comment: The areas are not fixed in place on modern systems. You could look at the file `/proc/self/maps` to find the stack position and size. There might be other files in the `/proc` filesystem, and system calls, to find the mapping of other things as well.

Comment: You can specify an initial memory map in the executable file of your program.  At runtime, you can modify this memory map with the `mmap` and `munmap` system calls.  As a rule of thumb, every C function listed in section 2 of the UNIX manual is a system call.  All of these can be called directly from assembly without using the libc, though using the libc is often a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Linux uses virtual memory (and [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)). Atari ST doesn't use either so it did have a fixed memory map for some OS data structures and code.  (Because the OS was in ROM and couldn't be easily updated, some people even documented some internal addresses.)

Linux tries to keep the boundary between kernel and user-space rigid, with a well-defined documented API / ABI for user-space to interact with the kernel via system calls.  (e.g. on x86-64, via the [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) instruction).  User-space doesn't need to care what's on the other side of that wall, and usually not even where its pages are in virtual memory as long as it has pointers to them.

When glibc `malloc` wants more pages from the OS, it uses `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` or `brk` to get them, and hand out chunks of them for small calls to `malloc`.  It keeps bookkeeping data structures in user-space (so that's per-process of course).

> I know Linux is set up differently and I kind of have the whole address space to myself, but I guess there are some memory areas I am not allowed to touch.

Yeah, every process has its own virtual address space.  You can only touch the parts you've allocated, otherwise the resulting page fault will be "invalid" (OS knows there isn't supposed to be a physical page for that virtual page) and will deliver a SIGSEGV signal to your process if you try to read or write it.  ("valid" page faults happen because of swap space or lazy allocation / copy-on-write; the kernel updates the HW page tables and returns to user-space for it to re-run the instruction that faulted.)

Also, the kernel claims the high half of virtual address space for its own use.  (https://wiki.osdev.org/Higher_Half_Kernel).  See also https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt for Linux's x86-64 memory map layout.

> I can't find any 'assembly' system call.

`mmap` and `brk` are true system calls. See the "notes" section of the [`brk(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html#NOTES).  Section 2 man pages are system calls, section 3 are libc functions.

Of course in C when you call `mmap(...)`, you're actually calling a wrapper function in glibc.  glibc provides wrapper functions, not inline asm macros that use the `syscall` instruction directly.

**See also [The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/)** which explains the asm interface, and also the VDSO pages.  Linux maps some kernel memory (read-only) into your user-space process, holding code and data so `getpid()` and `clock_gettime()` can run in user-space.

Also various Q&As on Stack Overflow, including [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6)

---

> So one of the things I am trying to find is how much memory is available to my program

There isn't a system call to query the current memory map of your process.  Parsing `/proc/self/maps` would be your best bet.

See [Finding mapped memory from inside a process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53022573) for some fun ideas on using system calls to scan ranges of virtual address space for mapped pages.  e.g. Like Linux's [`mincore(2)` syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html) returns `-ENOMEM` if the specified range contains any unmapped pages.